# Pepper robot: How to use tablet to send text input for further processing in Choregraphe?

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I need to send a user text input to the robot through the integrated tablet, and catch it somehow, for further processing in Choregraphe.

After reading the Aldebaran documentation about ALTabletService API, I found few methods which might be a solution to all this. The methods are ALTabletService::showInputTextDialog and ALTabletService::onInputText, but somehow I can't get them to work: they return absolutely nothing when I input some text through the tablet.

I need access to the string created when the user inputs a piece of text. Any advice how to do it?

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Answer (score 2):

i realized this without `ALTabletService` methods `showInputTextDialog` or `onInputText`

My Approach: 
I made an html page with an input field and a button to send the input.
On button press I use the `forceInput` method from `ALDialog` [doc](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog-api.html?highlight=forceinput#ALDialogProxy::forceInput__ssCR) via QiMessaging Javascript library. [doc](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html)

I can't test it right now but this should help as a inspiration

```
function forceInput(input) {
    QiSession(function(session) {
        session.service('ALDialog').then(function(ALDialog) {
            ALDialog.forceInput(input);
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can send the input to the topic.
This could be sth like "imput_from_tablet blablabla".
And in the Dialog you catch

```
u:(imput_from_tablet _*) $1
```

Where $1 should be blablabla.

Hope that helps
best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can create a webpage for the tablet and package it in your application - see the [documentation here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/creating_applications/using_peppers_tablet.html#showing-webpages); then on that webpage you can create a text input field (be careful that the bottom half of the screen will be hidden by the keyboard when the field is selected), and then use [the javascript SDK](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html#qimessaging-javascript) to (for example) raise an ALMemory event with the inputted text value, that you can then get from Choregraphe.

Comment: I know that you can create a webpage and to use HTML/JavaScript to create a dialog and get the input value. What I can't understand is the purpose of `ALTabletService::showInputTextDialog` if we haven't a method to get the value of the input text. Do you have any idea if this can be done?

Comment: I just saw that it can be done with [`qi::Signal<int, std::string> ALTabletService::onInputText`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::onInputText__qi::Signal:i.ss:) but I have not tried it yet

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I found this [ALTabletService::onInputText](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::onInputText__qi::Signal:i.ss:) method in the [signal list](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#signal-list). You can find examples how to use signals on the same page. Based on these examples I created the following script that can get a value from the input field:

```py
import qi
import sys

def main(app):
    try:
        session = app.session
        tabletService = session.service("ALTabletService")
        tabletService.showInputTextDialog("Example dialog", "OK", "Cancel")
        signal_id = 0

        def callback(button_id, input_text):
            if button_id == 1:
                print "'OK' button is pressed."
                print "Input text: " + input_text
            if button_id == 0:
                print "'Cancel' button is pressed"

            tabletService.onInputText.disconnect(signal_id)
            app.stop()

        # attach the callback function to onJSEvent signal
        signal_id = tabletService.onInputText.connect(callback)
        print "Signal ID: {}".format(signal_id)

        app.run()
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error was: ", e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = "10.0.10.254" # the IP of the robot
    port = 9559

    try:
        connection_url = "tcp://{}:{}".format(ip, port)
        app = qi.Application(url=connection_url)
        app.start()
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Can't connect to Naoqi.")
        sys.exit(1)
    main(app)
```

Comment: How I can Modify the code that after press 'OK' button the dialog will still open?